# can we found inner HREF values using selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Please find the below html code:

```
<fieldset class="attachmentTable large"><legend>SMF&nbsp;:</legend>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tr> <td> <a href="
/aems/file/test.html"> </a> </td>
<td>   foo     </td>
</tr>  </table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="attachmentTable large"><legend>tax&nbsp;:</legend>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tr> <td> <a href="

/relf/file/test.html">

</a></td>
<td>  foo   </td>
</tr> </table>
</fieldset>
```

Usinf `XPATH` and `selenium-webdriver` can we get the `/aems/file/test.html` from the part of the html?

Comment: How to get out `tax,SMF` values? I used `driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//fieldset[contains(@class,'attachmentTable')]/legend")`. But didn't get any values. Any mistake I did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should probably work for you

```
link = @driver.find_element(:xpath,"//fieldset[contains(@class,'attachmentTable')]/table/tr/td/a")
href= link.attribute("href")
puts href
```

**UPDATE**

Why I chose `contains` is because of [this](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/XPath%3a%20Select%20element%20by%20class.htm)

Comment: why you didn't take in the `:xpath` the element `legend`? Could you please explain?

Comment: because that does not come in the path, `legend`'s tag is closed before the element in question comes into picture. Why doesn this work for you ?

Comment: Yes,I just add it in my code, and ran the script. actually by mistake i added `legend` also in my `:xpath`,thus failed.

Comment: Cool, if this answer helped you, please mark this as the solution.

Comment: D:\Ruby script>download.rb
[remote server] file:///C:/Users/ARUPRA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20
130124-4648-ag7f6s/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_componen
t.js:8251:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_': Unable to locate el
ement: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//fieldset[@class='attachmentTable large']/
table/tr/td/a"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Comment: why you wrote only `attachmentTable` instead of `attachmentTable large`? Any reason?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23260/discussion-between-amey-and-dolovesky)

Comment: yes,it worked! but if possible please say me what i asked immediate above and one thing that you mispelled `:xpath` in your code :)