# Can we make these two loop combined means to run them parallel?

Tags: ruby

***Find the below code:***

```
all_links = driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//fieldset[contains(@class,'attachmentTable')]/table/tbody/tr/td/a")
all_attachment_names = driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//fieldset[contains(@class,'attachmentTable')]/legend")

all_links.each do|link|

href = link.attribute("href").strip
puts href
end

all_attachment_names.each do |name|

text = name.attribute("text")
puts text

end
```

1. Can we make these two loop combined means to run them `parallel`?
   provided that both of `loop count` is same.
2. I want to create `hash` where `key will be text` and `item will be
   href`.

Comment: who started such a poor down-voting game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) to do this:

```
returned_hash = {}
all_links.zip(all_attachment_names) do |link, name|
  returned_hash[name.text] = link.attribute("href").strip
end
```

You can also do it in a functional programming style by extracting the `href` and `text` with `map`:

```
hrefs = all_links.map{|link| link.attribute("href").strip}
names = all_attachment_names.map{|name| name.text}
returned_hash = Hash[names.zip(hrefs)]
```

Doing so is (arguably) more aesthetically pleasing but somewhat less efficient because it requires twice as many iterations, and creates a couple of extra arrays, but unless you have an enormous number of links that's not going to be an issue.

Comment: Why not `Hash[all_links.zip(all_attachment_names)]`?

Comment: Because you need to extract the `text` and `href` attributes from the array items

Comment: Then add 2 maps. I prefern functional programming :D

Comment: @AndyH perfect as you also took care of `href` and `text` also. `+1` to you!

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier Yeah, fair enough. Your solution was my first instinct too :) I'll add it as an addendum to my answer.

Comment: @AndyH Can you bit a look into [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489081/can-we-found-inner-href-values-using-selenium-webdriver/14489408#14489408)?

Answer (score 1):

```
map = {}
all_attachment_names.zip(all_links) do |a, l|
    map[a] = l
end
```

Comment: Why not `Hash[all_links.zip(all_attachment_names)]`?

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier because I didn't know about `Hash::[]`.